# How do I find out if my Questions\Answers have been edited

Tags: support, site-usage

This has been bugging me for a while, I can't see anyway find out which of my contributions have been edited ***by someone else***. I'd like to be able to check any edits to see if they have made material differences (either positive or negative, I'm not being precious, just curious).

Am I just missing something obvious or is this a feature that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't think to screencap it, but the few of my Q/A's that have been edited have shown up in the status thingy you get to when you click the Envelope.

[image]

Comment: There is a screencap for you.

Comment: Yipee! Community at its best.

Comment: Gotta +1 the HDCs.

Comment: I had a spate of edits to answers some time back where this didn't generate notifications me but clearly it's working as it should looking at Zoredache's screencap. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

If you click the "Revisions" tab after clicking the envelope icon you should be able to see them over the various time periods.

Also, there are notifications for these as sysadmin1138 mentioned.